# Code is not choosing negative numbers and returns 0 instead, how can i fix my code?

Tags: python

My mission is to create a function that return the minimum number from a list without using the min() function. When i run the following code, it return 0 instead of -1. I am not too sure why. Note: 1. fancy_min just returns the smaller number between the two parameters given.
2. If the list is empty or if the parameter is None, I want to return None.

```
def minimum_of(numbers):
  mini = 99999999
  if numbers == []:
    return None
  elif numbers is None:
    return None
  for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    m = fancy_min(numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
  if m<mini:
    return m

print(minimum_of([-1,3,None,2,1,]))

def fancy_min(a, b):
  while a is None:
    return b
  while b is None:
    return a
  if a > b:
    return b
  elif b > a:
    return a
```

Comment: what is `fancy_min`? please post the code

Comment: What does `fancy_min` return when one input is `None`?

Comment: I just added fancy min

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    m = fancy_min(numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
```

If you do this with the following array [1,2,3,4,5], m get the following values.

1. m = fancy_min(1, 2) | m = 1
2. m = fancy_min(2, 3) | m = 2
3. m = fancy_min(3, 4) | m = 3
4. m = fancy_min(4, 5) | m = 4

In order to return the minimum value of the array, I suggest the following.

```
smallest = numbers[0]
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] < smallest:
        smallest = numbers[i]
```

The for loop could be simplified with a for each loop like this.

```
for num in numbers:
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code is really returning 0 then it's most likely that the problem is within `fancy_min`. However, even with a good implementation of `fancy_min` there are some problems with the code, especially this:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    m = fancy_min(numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
```

Should be something like:

```
m = numbers[0]
for i in range(1, len(numbers)-1):
    m = fancy_min(m, numbers[i])
```

Although there are many things that could be done to simplify the code